# Any prefab stuff for organising a tournament?

Tags: php, python, ruby-on-rails, web-applications

Does anyone know if there are premade open source webapps not from 2005 (preferably PHP, but Rails/pYthon are fine) for an esports (specifically, counter-strike: source) tournament?

I've googled a fair bit and can't find anything serious.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll probably have to settle for old games, something like Quake 3/Unreal ... that's my guess

Comment: I don't really mind what it's for - that's why I want an open source script as opposed to be encrypted with ioncube loader or something. I do know basic bits of those languages enough to do basic modification

Comment: I've found a bit like some that only support PHP4 last updated half a decade ago, and half the results I see are on forum threads where the link to the actual author site no longer works and has been down for a long time :(

Comment: Do you anticipate having such a large number of players that handling the arrangements by hand in a spreadsheet would be too difficult? If you can't find anything good, you can always kick it ol' skool!

Comment: Only about 1500ish, by hand not happeing

Comment: As a note, tried webSPELL. Apparently does not like Percona MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

While this isnt open source per se I still think it can satisfy your needs.
Both [Binary Beast](http://binarybeast.com) and [Challonge](http://challonge.com) serves an API from which you can create and manage tournaments.
Binary Beast even provides libraries to interact with the API.
You will have to do some front end programming yourself or host it entirely on their site.

Comment: BinaryBeast somehow manages to not have its site at the top of google results, wtf?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as well, really strange.

Comment: I really need it self hosted entirely or as much as possible, under HTTPS, and intranet access :\